# VBA Offset within Loop - taking forever to run

Tags: vba, excel

I'm brand new to programming, and I figured VBA is a good place for me to start since I do a lot of work in Excel.

I created a macro that takes an integer from an input box (I've been using 2, 3 and 4 to test) and it creates a set of a 4-tier hierarchy of that number; e.g. entering "2" would produce

```
1.0.0.0
1.0.0.1
1.0.0.2
1.0.1.0
1.0.1.1
1.0.1.2 etc.
```

I got the macro to work as intended, but it takes forever to run. I think it's the offsets within the loops that are slowing it down. Does anyone have any suggestions to speed this up? Any general feedback is welcome as well.

```
Sub Tiers()

'Input Box
Dim Square As Integer
Square = InputBox("Enter Number of Tiers")
Range("f5").Select
Selection.Value = 0
 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Rows down
Dim g As Integer
Dim h As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

'Start For loops
For g = 1 To Square
    For h = 0 To Square
        For i = 0 To Square
            For j = 0 To Square

                'calculate offsets and place values of loop variables
                Dim step As Long
                step = ((g - 1) * (Square + 1) ^ 3 - 1 + (h * (Square + 1) ^ 2) + Square * i + i + j + 1)
                Selection.Offset(step, 0).Value = j
                Selection.Offset(step, -1).Value = i
                Selection.Offset(step, -2).Value = h
                Selection.Offset(step, -3).Value = g


            Next j
        Next i
    Next h
Next g

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the forums. What is `step = ((g - 1) * (Square + 1) ^ 3 - 1 + (h * (Square + 1) ^ 2) + Square * i + i + j + 1)`? Also looping and writing to sheets like this will be too slow. Write to an array and then write the array to worksheet

Comment: The "step" is the number of rows down that the offset goes to then place each variable. Each output (1 0 0 0, 1 0 0 1) is placed in an individual row across four columns (one per digit). And thank you, I will research arrays and figure out how to use those.

Comment: Declare/allocate a 2D variant array, populate the 2D array, dump the array onto the worksheet. You'll find that the less you read/write from/to the worksheet, the faster your code gets. `Selection` isn't supposed to change during the execution of the loop - it should be captured into a `Range` reference at the start of the procedure, and never invoked ever again. Repeatedly taking the `Selection`, accessing the `Offset` member of the `Range` interface through `IDispatch` late-bound calls (because `Selection` is `Object`, not `Range`), is what's killing it.

Comment: Also note, `Step`, as in `For i = 9 To 0 Step -1`, is a keyword, or should be treated as one: avoid using language keywords as identifiers, even if the compiler lets you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Further to my comment below your post, looping and writing to sheets like this will be too slow. Write to an array and then write the array to worksheet. This ran in a blink of an eye.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim TempArray() As Long
    Dim n As Long
    Dim g As Long, h As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim reponse As Variant

    '~~> Accept only numbers
    reponse = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter Number of Tiers", Type:=1)

    If reponse <> False Then
        For g = 1 To reponse
            For h = 0 To reponse
                For i = 0 To reponse
                    For j = 0 To reponse
                        n = n + 1
                    Next j
                Next i
            Next h
        Next g

        ReDim Preserve TempArray(1 To n, 1 To 4)
        n = 1

        For g = 1 To reponse
            For h = 0 To reponse
                For i = 0 To reponse
                    For j = 0 To reponse
                        TempArray(n, 1) = g
                        TempArray(n, 2) = h
                        TempArray(n, 3) = i
                        TempArray(n, 4) = j
                        n = n + 1
                    Next j
                Next i
            Next h
        Next g

        '~~> Replace this with the relevant sheet
        Sheet1.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(TempArray), 4).Value = TempArray
    End If
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

Comment: Yes it ran very fast, it looks like 31 is the max you can enter before running out of room

Comment: yes. It took 3 seconds for me for `31` and reached `A1015808`. For `33` it gave an error as it needs `1297032` rows.

Comment: Amazing... this is exactly it, thank you!

So, it looks like you have one set of loops to create the size of the array and then the second set to place the values in the array? Is it possible to do both at the same time?

Comment: @dmihel: You are welcome :) I would recommend reading up on arrays. See this [LINK](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: You don't need the first loop.  Calculate `n` from `responce`.  Untested, I think its `n = ( response +1)^3 × responce`

Answer (score 1):

The `step` calculation seems superfluous:

> ```
> step = ((g - 1) * (Square + 1) ^ 3 - 1 + (h * (Square + 1) ^ 2) + Square * i + i + j + 1)
> ```

Try the following:

```
Sub Tiers()

'Input Box
Dim Square As Long
Square = InputBox("Enter Number of Tiers")
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

'Rows down
Dim g As Long
Dim h As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim step As Long

step = 1

For g = 1 To Square
    For h = 0 To Square
        For i = 0 To Square
            For j = 0 To Square
                Range("F5").Offset(step, 0).Value = j
                Range("F5").Offset(step, -1).Value = i
                Range("F5").Offset(step, -2).Value = h
                Range("F5").Offset(step, -3).Value = g
                step = step + 1
            Next j
        Next i
    Next h
Next g

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Ha... You are correct. Kind of funny to see that formula rendered superfluous by "x = x+1" I definitely should have thought of that, thanks.